# CiviMail: Send to Individual Contacts (not just Groups)?

Tags: civimail

Is there an option in CiviMail to allow us to add individuals (not groups) in the Recipients field when creating a new Mailing? (we're using Mosaico/FlexMailer, if that helps).

We're trying to avoid having to put people into temporary groups each time we want to send a mass mailing. Sometimes new individuals come in after we've sent the mail mailing, and we want to resend only to those individuals, without having to add them into a temp group and then delete the group.

If there isn't an out-of-the-box option for this, any pointers to where we might be able to customize the new mailing screen to add this?

Comment: I would use smart group to add those new contacts, so the group would automatically be updated at the time of sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you want to do, but if you install the [Resend Mailing](https://github.com/artfulrobot/resendmailing) extension, you can select one or more contacts from search results and use the action drop down menu to resend a mailing to those specific contacts.

Alternatively, you could just add the new recipients to the original group you used for the mailing and resend the mailing, subtracting the recipients of the original mailing and thus only sending it to the new group members.

Comment: sounds like a very good suggestion